# excel - VBA - I cannot refresh a shape conditional formatting linked to a formulas after a cell refresh

Tags: excel, vba

I need your help. 
context: I have a VBA to change colors (Green, Orange, Red) to several shapes linked to a % value. The values will change based on a list box. However if the % change, the formatting do not follow.

The macro is as the following - would you know how to "force" the refresh so that the Shape formatting follow any cell changes? below attempt to force it failed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    EnableFormatConditionsCalculation = True    
    If Target.Address = "$K$16" Then 
    With Sheets("Resources").Shapes("Oval 1")    
    If Sheets("Resources").Cells(16, 11).Value < 0.95 Then 
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)    
    Else If 
    Sheets("Resources").Cells(16, 11).Value > 0.99 Then 
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)    
    Else 
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 0)    
    End If    
    End If    
    End With    
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$L$16" Then 
    With Sheets("Resources").Shapes("Oval 2")    
    If Sheets("Resources").Cells(16, 12).Value < 0.95    Then 
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)    
    Else If Sheets("Resources").Cells(16, 12).Value > 0.99    Then 
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)    
    Else 
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 0)     
    End If    
    End If    
    End With 
    Range("K16:W16").Calculate    
    End If    

End Sub
```

Comment: Please fix your code formatting

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you, I just tried to reedits it and place the 4 space as mentioned into the instructions - apologize, it is my first post and this means I spent hours on this problem turning it around that I came at the point I need an expert eyes to help me out ;) Thanks in advance.

Comment: I made a start for you - all you need to do now is fix the indenting...

Comment: You maybe need to respond to the `Calculate` event if the changes are not being made directly in the cells you're monitoring

Comment: How would you do that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    CheckFormat Me.Range("K16"), "Oval 1"
    CheckFormat Me.Range("L16"), "Oval 2"

End Sub

Sub CheckFormat(valueRange As Range, shapeName As String)
    Dim v, clr As Long
    v = valueRange.Value 

    If Len(v) = 0 Then
        clr = RGB(255, 255, 255) '<< EDIT: use white if no value
    Else
        If v < 0.95 Then
            clr = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ElseIf v > 0.99 Then
            clr = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        Else
            clr = RGB(255, 153, 0)
        End If
    End If
    Me.Shapes(shapeName).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = clr
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked out many thanks :) one more question if I might Tim - how would you make it than in case K16 is filled but L16 is empty, only Oval1 is refreshed and Oval2 would go white as ex. - just an embellishment if it could work.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough - it work very well, thank you so much for that

Answer (score 0):

**Worksheet_Change** will be launched if any of cells will be changed manually by user. It will not be triggered if any of your formulas like **RANDBETWEEN** will bring new value.

You might be interested in reforging your routine to a VBA formula of a [VOLATILE](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/volatile-functions.html) type. Click the link to follow some of the instructions. Long story short - you can place a special command into your User Defined Function so it will run each time something changes in your workbook. And that formula you could place into **$K$16** cell.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Roman  - would you know how to place this volatile function into my macro above or do I really need a new module for it and if yes, how to call back to the $K$16 cell - the range is from K:16 - W:16 with each of them a dedicated shape for the formatting. Thank you

Comment: What exact formula do you have inside $K$16 cell? New UDF will be copying it's calculations and repeat your SUB code.

Comment: it refers to a calculation  on another worksheets
=IFERROR('Graph Data'!C303,"")

and the C303 is having the following formulas :
=IF('GM Track'!E3="Act",'GM Track'!E56/'GM Track'!E58,NA())